# Values changed when exporting python sparse matrix to matlab

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, scipy

I was trying to export a very large matrix  `1000000x207080 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'`returned by CountVectorizer to MATLAB using `io.savemat`. The matrix contains 1's and 0's. However when I load the mat file in matlab it contains some exponents and now I can't use it as a bag of words matrix anymore. How to convert the type `numpy.int64` into `numpy.int32` for the matrix?

Comment: I changed by passing dtype = numpy.int32 but now all values have become 1 or 2 or 3 instead of original 1 and 0.

Comment: Does this just occur with the very large matrix, or is true of smaller ones with similar values?  For example if you save a slice of the original. To print more help you may have to show the smallest sparse matrix that has this problem.  Also what happens when you reload the matrix into python?

Comment: astype fixed it! Thanks! 1 and 2 are perfectly acceptable!